# Yii2: можно ли добавить свой метод в ActiveRecord?

Tags: yii2, activerecord

У меня есть класс `User`. Когда я хочу выбрать все пользователей, я делаю запрос

```
User::find()->all()
```

Когда надо добавить условие - добавляю `where`. Но, например, мне надо много где использовать 3-4 одинаковых условий

```
User::find()->where(['status' => 1, 'rating' => 0, 'balance' => 0])
```

Я хотел бы иметь некий метод `selectNewUser()` который смог бы вызвать так

```
User::find()->selectNewUser()->all()
```

Это реально? Не могу нагуглить информацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно с помощью `ActiveQuery`. Инфу можно почитать тут https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/db-active-record/#customizing-query-classes

Также сразу оговорюсь, что эти классы можно генерировать в `gii` при генерировании модели:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как добиться:

- Создаётся отдельный класс, унаследованный от `ActiveQuery`. Обычно они все лежат в  папке и в неймспейсе `app\models\query;`
- В классе выше необходимо переопределить два метода `one` и `all`

  ```
    /**
     * Данный класс ActiveQuery является надстройкой для основного [[\app\models\Comment]].
     */
    class CommentQuery extends ActiveQuery {

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         *
         * @return \app\models\Comment[]|array
         */
        public function all($db = null) {
            return parent::all($db);
        }

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         *
         * @return \app\models\Comment|array|null
         */
        public function one($db = null) {
            return parent::one($db);
        }
    }
  ```
- В основной модели надо сделать ссылку на модель `ActiveQuery`:

  ```
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * @return \app\models\query\CommentQuery the active query использующаяся для  данного класса AR.
     */
    public static function find() {
        return new \app\models\query\CommentQuery(get_called_class());
    }
  ```
- Теперь в классе `ActiveQuery` можно писать доп. методы

  ```
    public function active($state = true) {
        return $this->andWhere(['active' => $state]);
    }
  ```

  Этот метод будет выбирать только активных или только неактивных пользователей.
- Применение:

  ```
  $comments = Comment::find()->active()->all();
  $inactiveComments = Comment::find()->active(false)->all();
  ```

---

В вашем случае метод может быть таким:

```
public function activeWithZeroBalanceAndRating() {
    return $this->andWhere(['status' => 1, 'rating' => 0, 'balance' => 0]);
}
```

И использование:

```
$activeUsersWIthZeorBalanceAndRating = User::find()->activeWithZeroBalanceAndRating()->all();
```

Конечно, если нужно, то можно сделать метод с параметрами и передавать данные туда, как в примерах выше.